# Auto-run on Windows startup

Tags: java, windows, startup, autorun

I have a client-server application in Java and it is basically a remote control software. I need client to run in Windows startup, I searched and found some ways to do that.

1- Adding shortcut or file to Startup folder

I can't do that since there is a possibility to user can delete it from folder.

2- Writing it to registry
That's exactly what I want but, I don't want to use 3rd part applications or sources. I couldn't find a way to do that on my own.

3- Wrapping it as a windows service
That's also okey for me, however, there will be multiple client's so i need to do that process each time. Thus I can't use it.

If you can help me, give me an idea or indicate my mistakes on topic, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Task Scheduler.  This would allow you to run it on boot as well as other types of triggers.

https://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, since there is hundreds of client computers, it can't be handled by manual. I need client to do it automatically, a bunch of code maybe.

Comment: Tasks can be triggered by whatever events you want them to be triggered by.
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/advanced-users-task-creation-task-scheduler/